# How to Prove this Fractional Linear Transformation of $\mathbb C$ takes $S^1$ to itself?

Tags: general-topology, functions, complex-numbers

Let $x\in\mathbb C$.  I know that $|x|<1$ but I don't think that matters for what I'm about to ask.  Let $f$ be the fractional linear transformation $f(z)=\frac{z-x}{1-\overline x z}$.  Then I'm told $|z|=1$ $\Longrightarrow$ $|f(z)|=1$.  Is that obvious?

Comment: Hint: Compute $|f(z)|$ using your formula.

Comment: IIRC there are two observation at play.1) $z\overline{z}=1$ if and only if $|z|=1$. 2) $|w/\overline{w}|=1$ for all non-zero complex numbers $w$. Play with them.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z|=1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{z-x}{1-\overline{x}z}\right|&=\left|\frac{z-x}{\overline{z}z-\overline{x}z}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{z-x}{(\overline{z}-\overline{x})z}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{z-x}{\overline{z-x}}\right|\frac{1}{|z|}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, that rocks. I don't know why it gave me so much trouble.  Replacing $1$ by $\overline zz$ was clever.